# Convert aws cli JSON output

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jq, aws-cli, key-value

The below aws cli command returns the following

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name home-automation-service --region us-east-1 --query "Stacks[0].Outputs[*].{OutputKey:OutputKey,OutputValue:OutputValue}"  --output json


[
    {
        "OutputKey": "URLPath",
        "OutputValue": "https://home-automation-service.jakeworld.com"
    },
    {
        "OutputKey": "Port",
        "OutputValue": "8080"
    }    
]
```

I want to convert the json to resemble the following

```
    {
        "URLPath": "https://home-automation-service.jakeworld.com",
        "Port": "8080"
    }
```

Can this be done using the `--query` parameter in the aws cli? If not, appreciate help using any other way of doing it?

Comment: Will it always be these outputs, or are you looking for a generic solution?

Comment: I am looking for a generic solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A jq solution:

```
map( {(.OutputKey) : .OutputValue} ) | add
```